# SAML 2.0 based single sign on

Tags: authentication, saml

We got the following error while "Integrating WSO2 with Facebook":

> SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On
>   Error when processing the authentication request!
>   Please try login again

[image]

Can anyone suggest us, where we are getting these issue.
Below are the logs that we got:

> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-10-18 05:06:33,492] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler}
>   -  Received access token is invalid. org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.AuthenticationFailedException:
>   Received access token is invalid.
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(FacebookAuthenticator.java:232)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.process(AbstractApplicationAuthenticator.java:69)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.doAuthentication(DefaultStepHandler.java:466)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handleResponse(DefaultStepHandler.java:440)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler.handle(DefaultStepHandler.java:144)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.handle(DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler.java:175)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.handle(DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler.java:127)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:142)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:53)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:43)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.filter.CaptchaFilter.doFilter(CaptchaFilter.java:76)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:72)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.ApplicationAuthenticatorException:
>   Received access token is invalid.
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator.getToken(FacebookAuthenticator.java:256)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.facebook.FacebookAuthenticator.processAuthenticationResponse(FacebookAuthenticator.java:210)

Comment: We are using WSO2 5.3.0 Identity server to integrate with Facebook

Comment: Hi Krishna! Please follow proper formatting when posting  [Formatting Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Also include what have you done so far and what output you're looking for. This will help the community understand your situation better and in return you can get more accurate answers. Thanks!

Comment: I think you are going to have to try and find som more detailed logs. maby you need to turn on debuglogging levels